How to access previous versions of merge requests on gitlab?
Gitlab exposes the refs for merge requests with something like:
git ls-remote
458e39b185e392de960de765289a4bfcff5f2fe5        refs/merge-requests/113/head
61e363607cf9fcbaf8eb1a7f0ab13cc3d2daf678        refs/merge-requests/113/merge

if one would want to do a completely local review workflow, these could be added to fetch, reflog could be turned on, so any changes could be tracked with git range-diff` based on the reflog, but this only works for changes I've seen (fetched). Which is I guess somewhat okay, since I'm probably interested in changes since I've last reviewed, but still it would be nice to be able to get all versions of the merge request locally.
Any ideas how to achieve this?
